# Combination of a normal r.v. with a log-normal one

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

It is well-known that a sum of normal r.v.'s is another normal r.v., and a sum of log-normal r.v.'s can be accurately *approximated* with a log-normal r.v. But what can we say if we have a mixture of both types is the sum? Is there any other approximation?

The second question is regarding the product. Again, it is not a secret that a product of log-normal r.v.'s is another log-normal r.v., and a product of normal r.v.'s is already not that straight-forward. But can one draw any conclusion regardig the product of normal and log-normal r.v.'s?

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: A sum of log-normal random variables can be accurately approximated with a log-normal random variables, but *only at its right-tail*. This shows the meaning of *approximate* should be made much more specific here.

Comment: @Ivan, was my answer below of any help?

Comment: @justin, yes, thanks!

Comment: glad I could help...I've got lots of helpful answers from others so it's nice when I can actually give back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, there is a significant amount of research on what is called the "Normal Log-normal Mixture" distribution. (NLN)

The form of the RV is:

$x=e^{\nu /2}\varphi $

Where $\nu$ and $\varphi$ are random variables satisfying:
 $\begin{bmatrix}
\varphi\\
\nu
\end{bmatrix} \sim N\left ( \begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\ 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1 &\rho \sigma \\ 
\rho\sigma &\sigma^2 
\end{bmatrix} \right )$

There are a number of extensions from here, but this is a general beginning point to products of these two distributions.